# Powershell: Cast object inside select-object

Tags: powershell

I want to cast an object inside a `Select-Object`

I can't seem to get the syntax right :(

```
Select-Object `
                @{name='a';expression={$path}}, `
                @{name='b';expression={$folder}}, `
                @{Name='c';expression={ [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}}, `
                @{Name='SID';expression={$_.IdentityReference}}
```

Keep getting empty string.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned what I am trying to do here. `IdentityReference` seems to be giving me a SID, I just want to convert it to name.

@briantist - yes the cast works outside, try `([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]"S-1-5-XX-VALID-SID-HERE").Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value` which I started with.

@TessellatingHeckler `$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])`didn't work sadly.

Comment: Does the cast work outside of `Select-Object`?

Comment: e.g. `'4'|select @{N='nocast';E={$_+1}},@{N='cast';E={[int]$_+1}}|fl` - casting to `[int]` works inside the expression, so you don't wrong syntax. If the expression throws an exception for any reason it is suppressed and you get nothing, e.g. `'a'|select @{N='cast';E={[int]$_+1}}|fl`. What type is `$_`? because I can't quickly make that cast work from a FileSystemAccessRule / NTAccount. It looks like you get a username, translate to username, get the username value, then cast to a SID. Could you directly `$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])`?

Comment: `([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$_.IdentityReference).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value`

Comment: @PetSerAl - It's giving me empty string. I must be missing something. I took the same SID and tested the cast as per my edit, but when running it in the `select-object` i seem to be getting empty string. How could I put a write-host in to test what it actually giving me?

Comment: Try to use `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object` and test just problem expression. `Select-Object` seems to hide any errors, preventing normal debugging.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to troubleshoot if we knew what type of object was in the pipeline or what cmdlet you used to create the object in the pipeline.

Comment: What version of PowerShell is this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a bit more code?
This works for me:

```
Select-Object `
            @{name='a';expression={$path}}, `
            @{name='b';expression={$folder}}, `
            @{Name='c';expression={((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList "SID").Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value}}, `
            @{Name='SID';expression={$_.IdentityReference}}
```

Replace with the input.

> -ArgumentList "SID"